# Issue sending email using Gmails SMTP server

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

Ive written an application which sends notifications to people via email. For testing purposes im using Gmails SMTP server. Using the below code im testing but im randomly getting the below error.

I'm using smtp.gmail.com on port 587

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at    
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)    
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)    
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)    
   at EmailAlertService.Email.sendMail(String subject, String body, String[] recipients, String from, String& error)
```

About 1 out of 5 emails generates this exception. 
I'm using the same credentials and to/from address combo for every test.
Any idea if its something im doing or is it Gmails servers throwing a fit!

```
   public bool sendMail(string subject, string body, string[] recipients, string from, ref string error)
    {            
        bool success = recipients != null && recipients.Length > 0;

        if (success)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = hostName,
                Port = port,
                EnableSsl = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
            };


            using (MailMessage gMessage = new MailMessage(from, recipients[0], subject, body))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(recipients[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < recipients.Length; i++) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(recipients[i]);
                    gMessage.To.Add(recipients[i]);
                }

                try
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(gMessage);
                    success = true;
                    error = string.Empty;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    success = false;
                    error = ex.ToString();

                }
            }
        }
        else
            error = "No destination email addresses supplied";

        return success;
    }
```

Comment: Is it a timing issue?  Are you sending all 5 at once or staggering them?  Try introducing a delay into your sending of the emails to see if it is an issue where Google thinks you are trying to mass email.  I am just guessing, but worth a look.

Comment: My Emails are in a loop but require a keypress between each email. Im waiting a few seconds between each attempt. But sometimes it fails on the 1st attempt and succeeds with the rest.

Comment: Are you trying to test the sending of emails through GMail or are you just using GMail as your test SMTP server?  In other words, is GMail going to be your real SMTP server?

Comment: I have not decided what im using for my real server. I might use gmail. At the moment im just testing the email sending functionality.